# npm installing package thats not mentioned in package.json during Jenkins build

Tags: angular, user-interface, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, semantic-versioning

this is my first post, please let me know if I've missed adding any details or explanations for my question.

I'm trying to perform basic npm install and am receiving the following error.

```
npm ERR! code E403
npm ERR! 403 403 -------------------->>> REQUESTED ITEM IS QUARANTINED -------------------->>> FOR DETAILS SEE ------>>> https://applicationevaluation.fanniemae.com:8443/ui/links/repository/c7d7996dc9554ecc8fcc81a178ebc533/result <<<------ - GET http://plsysadm-ap59:8081/nexus/repository/npm-all/semver/-/semver-6.3.1.tgz
npm ERR! 403 In most cases, you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! 403 a package version that is forbidden by your security policy, or
npm ERR! 403 on a server you do not have access to.
```

I understand its due to the quarantined dependency from my organization's repository. What I've tried so far

1. specifically mention a different version of "semver" in package.json and do npm i, it failed
2. run npm update - which failed,
3. clear cache and npm i, failed
4. deleted node_module and package-lock.json and tried npm i, it failed as well.

Before is my package.json for reference. Any help would be of huge help

```
{
  "name": "local-ui",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build-prod-win": ".\\node_modules\\.bin\\ng build --configuration production --base-href . --output-hashing none",
    "build-prod-unix": "./node_modules/.bin/ng build --configuration production --base-href . --output-hashing none",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/common": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/core": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/router": "^15.2.9",
    "@blueprint/cxd-blueprint-ui": "3.0.0",
    "caniuse-lite": "1.0.30001322",
    "electron-to-chromium": "1.4.99",
    "eslint": "^8.44.0",
    "express": "4.17.1",
    "json5": "2.2.3",
    "jszip": "3.10.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.7",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/cli": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/language-service": "^15.2.9",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.9",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "json-server": "^0.16.1",
    "karma": "~6.3.20",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.9.5"
  }
}
```

What I've tried

1. run npm update which failed,
2. specifically mention a different version of "semver" in package.json, it failed
3. clear cache and npm i, failed
4. deleted node_module and package-lock.json and tried npm i, it failed as well.

Expecting
To understand why is this dependency being installed. Please let me know if this post needs any additional details since its my first post

**QUICK UPDATE!!!!**
I found 3 subdepndencies of @babel which were using "semver: 6.3.1". I changed them to 6.3.0.
I've also update this at bottom of my package.json
"overrides": {
"semver": "6.3.0"
}
The error got solved in my local. However when I deploy this is my Jenkins server, I'm still getting the old error. I did not receive the "old lockfile" and  "EBADENGINE" warning in my local ever.

```
npm WARN old lockfile 
npm WARN old lockfile The package-lock.json file was created with an old version of npm,
npm WARN old lockfile so supplemental metadata must be fetched from the registry.
npm WARN old lockfile 
npm WARN old lockfile This is a one-time fix-up, please be patient...
npm WARN old lockfile 
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'lru-cache@10.0.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '14 || >=16.14' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.13.0', npm: '8.1.0' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm ERR! code E403
npm ERR! 403 403 -------------------->>> REQUESTED ITEM IS QUARANTINED -------------------->>> FOR DETAILS SEE ------>>> https://*****/result <<<------ - GET http:/***/semver-6.3.1.tgz
npm ERR! 403 In most cases, you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! 403 a package version that is forbidden by your security policy, or
npm ERR! 403 on a server you do not have access to.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

Things done in Jenkins file before the npm install in Jenkins are

```
 '''POM_VERSION=$(head -20 pom.xml | sed '7!d' | sed -e 's/.*<version>\\(.*\\)<\\/version>/\\1/')
                                       VERSION=$POM_VERSION
                                       java -version
                                       mvn -version
                                       npm config delete proxy
                                       npm config delete http-proxy
                                       npm config delete https-proxy
                                       npm config set registry http:/***/
                                       npm cache clean --force
                                       npm cache verify 
                                       echo "---------Cleared cache files------------"
                                       mvn -U clean install -Dbuild-angular-ui -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true -B -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.org.apache.maven.cli.transfer.Slf4jMavenTransferListener=warn
                                       '''
```

I'm sure I'm missing something basic. Please let me know what can be tried differently.

Comment: Can you use the package-lock.json to determine which of your dependencies is relying on a particular version of semver?

Comment: Having the exact same problem. semver 6.3.1 was added to quarantine July 10th and builds have been breaking since then. I think the problem is in Angular for me, we're using 13.*, when Angular 14.2.12 bumps the semver version to 7.5. Have not been able to find a fix since there are other org dependencies that seems to rely on Angular 13.*

Comment: Though maybe not now that I'm looking at your package.json and see Angular. Mine is very similar.